# crawler in laravel using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

now im implement laravel project to crawler value from tiktok site using GuzzleHttp.

for example. i want to crawl data from this url

`https://www.tiktok.com/@zihaolol98`

and I want to collect Name, Profile Picture, number of followers.

From now, i just success to colect the name. here is my code.

```
   $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

   //Get Name
   $response = $client->get('https://www.tiktok.com/@zihaolol98', ['headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'spider']]);
   preg_match_all('/<header(.*?)class="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/header>/s', $response->getBody(), $getname);
   preg_match_all('/<h1(.*?)class="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/h1>/s', $getname[3][0], $name_found);
   $name = $name_found[3][0];
```

it return `zihaolol98` as a name

next, i want to collect Profile picture and number of followers. i already tried this code but still failed. here is the code

```
   //crawl Profile Picture
   preg_match_all('/jsx-\d{10}(.*?)jsx-\d{10}(.*?)(.*?)jsx-\d{10}(.*?)avatar-wrapper(.*?)/s', $response->getBody(), $picture_matches);
   dump($picture_matches); 

   //crawl followers
   preg_match_all('/title="Followers"/s', $response->getBody(), $follower);
   dump($follower);
```

if we see the inspect element on browser, i want the code return the value

profile picture `https://mpak-suse1.akamaized.net/res/usericon/304/icon-56105311844962304-425.jpg`

followers `330.6K`

please help me for that. it is possible for return the value like i want?

Comment: Have any error??

Comment: no error. but it return empty array. not return name, image, and follower number value

Comment: Please debug your code at first. Test if your initial request actually returns your expected HTML code, for example by adding `var_dump($response->getBody())`.

Additionally, the share regex filters for a class with the name *"jsx-2971206140"*, which looks like a possible dynamic class to me. Did you verify, that it is always that exact number? If not, you need to adjust your regex to match for a dynamic mumber. (For example with `jsx-\d{10}`)

Comment: Acutally, it would be great if your could provide a **short** example HTML code for wich you would expect your code to match specific elements.

Comment: until now. i just succed to crawler the tiktok name. but for the profile picture and number of followers still confuse.  @phi

Comment: Hello @ferdinand. Please try to be as technical precise as possible. Instead of stating that you succeded in crawling a tiktok name, edit your question and tell us what part you checked and which part did not work exactly. Try to explain it based on your code, not based on your user experience.

Comment: thank you @PhilippMaurer i aleady edited my question for more detail.